# How to pass exception from Server to Client side in GWT RPC

Tags: gwt, exception, rpc, gwt-rpc

I am creating a RPC call using Async method in GWT. I have to check if there is any error on my Server side. Can I catch the exceptions of the server side on the Client side in GWT RPC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exceptions have to be declared in a `throws` clause in your `RemoteService` interface's methods, and have to be serializable by GWT-RPC under the same conditions as any other transported class.

You'll receive the exception in your `AsyncCallback`'s `onFailure`. See also the [javadoc for `AsyncCallback`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/AsyncCallback.html).

---

**EDIT:** actually, it happens that I just said the same thing that the doc already says: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideHandlingExceptions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Just make sure that your exception implements Serializable:

```
public class LoginException extends Exception implements Serializable {

    public LoginException() {
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to pull an external servers information to the RPC Server and then trying to display the information on my client side. Will this work in this case as well? Should I just extend this Exception class in my Server side implementation and put it in the TRY-CATCH block to send the exception over to the client side of RPC.

Comment: If an external exception is serializable, you can simply throw it in your RPC method. If not, you can create your own exception, set a message that you want, and throw it instead.

Comment: ...and is declare as a `throws` in your RPC interface. Without that, GWT doesnt know you want to send it.